# What is a place in the U.S.A that is between 40°F - 60°F (5°C - 15°C) year round and doesn't get a ton of rain?

Tags: united-states, weather, temperature

I just wanted to know what place in america has forest, temperature ranges from 40°F - 60°F (5°C - 15°C) year round, does NOT rain for days on end, and rarely gets snow.

I tried looking around on the internet for the answer to this question. The closest I got was Eureka, California. I don't care if it's cloudy most of the time, as long as it's not super rainy. But I had the impression that Eureka is really rainy.

Comment: Olympic Peninsula. There's a reason things stay the same temperature year round, usually it's called a Maritime Climate. Precipitation is one of the side effects.

Comment: 40-60 average daily temperature, or average *range* of daily temperature? The former includes huge swaths of the West inland from the coastal mountain ranges, whereas the latter is limited to the Pacific Northwest. WeatherDB.com can help give you a picture.

Comment: Yes, Eureka is quite rainy, as is everyplace on the west slope of the costal range in the pacific northwest. In fact, that's where some of the highest rainfalls (and snowfalls) are recorded in the US. There is a similar but smaller region in Hawaii, which I think has the actual highest rainfal in the US if I remember right. The highest snowfall, again if I remember right, is at Paradise Ranger Station on the west slope of Mt Rainier.

Comment: [Mammoth Cave National Park](https://www.nps.gov/maca/index.htm) in Central Kentucky.  It is an almost constant 54F and it absolutely never rains.  Granted, you have to be *inside* the cave to experience this climate.  There are similar cave systems elsewhere.

Comment: that narrow a range would tend to be oceanic climate, which usually goes with tons of rain.

Answer (score 13):

There is no such place.  40-60°F is a *very* narrow range.  20°F can be just from day and night variation, which leaves basically nothing for seasonal variation.

Even if you meant daytime highs, I still don't think there is any place on earth that fits this description, let alone anywhere in the US.

Let's flip this around and think of what would make a place have very low temperature variation.  Seasonal variations get larger towards the poles, so starting in the tropics is probably a good idea.  60°F is very low for the tropics, so that means moving up in altitude.

Even ignoring the rain criterion, this still sounds like a impossible goal.  Imagine looking for this place by trying different elevations in the Andes near the equator.  By the time you get to 60°F highs, you will be well below freezing at other times.  Obviously anyplace with snow on the ground, ever, doesn't fit your criteria.

Again, there is no such place here on earth in the open.  What you ask does exist in caves.

Comment: San Francisco comes pretty darn close. Born and raised there and the range is pretty close to the OP's requirements.

Comment: Anywhere on Earth, Quito, Ecuador comes close (waiving the forest requirement)

Comment: @M.Mat, I have only visited San Fran once, but it was considerably warmer than 15°C, and I'd be surprised to hear that was some freak incident...

Comment: There are a number of warm days—Spring and Fall in particular, but SF is mild, and cool normally. San Francisco is at the tip of a peninsula, surrounded by water on three sides and it has its own climate—which can vary from neighborhood to neighborhood. It is not unheard of for it to be raining at the beach and sunny in the Mission. As someone born and raised in the City, I stand behind my statement.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you will get consistent 40-60 daytime highs (what I assumed you meant) anywhere that isn't moderated by the ocean.  However Fiasco is correct:  The Olympic Penninsula around Sequim is very close.  Summer temps are cool enough that tomatoes won't rippen outside of a greenhouse.  Winter has frosts, but not consitently.  The mountains nearby get significant snow.

Another possibility is the "Sunshine Coast" in British Columbia -- that's the east side of the Georgia Straight. You have Vancouver island acting as a rain screen.  Not as dry as Sequim.  It however still gets frosts in winter, and on a summer day it will usually be in the 70's, and sometimes in the 90's

Failing that:  In general you want the east side of a coastal range of mountains, a range that is high enough to precipitate out most of the rain.  Interior ranges will do the same thing to precipitation, but they will have more continental climates so the temperature range will be significantly greater.

As you move south, the temps get warmer.  Compensate for this by moving higher.  The tradeoff, is you get more cloud spilling over the tops.

Take a look at the east slopes on the north island of New Zeeland.

A final suggestion is the coast of Peru and Chile.  The Humbolt current is cold, and wrings out most of the moisture of clouds passing over.  Archeologies still talk about discoveries made after the 1923 Rain.  Apparently that's the last time it did rain.  Lots of fog, no rain.  However it is hot in summer.

You may want to migrate:  Have two households.  Become a snowbird.

Answer (score 5):

I think [Mauna Kea](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauna_Kea) in Hawaii may meet your requirements. The average highs at the summit are between 40.3 and 50.9 F with most months having less than an inch of rain. The average lows at the summit are between 24.9 and 31.3 F making it a little too cold. Further, the summit is above tree line. Tree line (and the forest zone) is about 4000' below the summit so there should be a sweet spot where you can get limited rain, forest, and temperatures consistently between 40 and 60 F.

Comment: Can you live there?

Comment: @M.Mat if you are willing to join the Army you could live at the [Pohakuloa Training Area](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohakuloa_Training_Area) although its elevation is lower so probably has high temperatures over 60 F and I cannot tell if it is on the rainy side or not. You could also try living in the cabins at [Auna Kea State Recreation area](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauna_Kea_State_Recreation_Area) or in the dorms of the [Onizuka Center for International Astronomy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onizuka_Center_for_International_Astronomy) again, I am not sure about the.

Comment: @StongBad Been there, done that. Retired USAF. I have been to Onizuka and did a TDY at Onizuka AS in the SF Bay Area. P.S. Was born at The Presidio San Francisco, former home of the U.S. Sixth Army.

Answer (score 4):

I was going to submit my hometown of San Francisco as a candidate. It rains far less than in the Pacific Northwest and because of terrain and the micro-climates in this tiny city of 49 square miles, it stays pretty cool in a number of different neighborhoods. The Sunset or The Richmond districts could be possible.[image: San Francisco Climate] 
http://www.usclimatedata.com/climate/san-francisco/california/united-states/usca0987
[image: Sunset District] [image: Richmond District] While there is no forest per se, there is the splendid, magnificent [Golden Gate Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Gate_Park) (larger than NYC's Central Park). [image: Stowe Lake] [image: Botanical Gardens]  [image: Aerial GGP] As you can see, it's quite large, is truly lush and NO SNOW!

Answer (score 1):

There are several places in the US that meet your requirement if you exclude the requirement for forest, and you are will to accept no snow, in place of rare snow.

> what place in america has forest, temperature ranges from 40-60 degrees year round, does NOT rain for days on end, and rarely gets snow. (*from question*)

With requirements

- temperature ranges from 40-60 degrees year round
- does NOT rain...
- no snow

Most notably is [Mammoth Cave](https://www.nps.gov/maca/index.htm) but it is in a national park, so it is not a viable solution for a long term living solution. If you stay away from the entrance, the temp is mostly stable at 54 degrees, it never rains or snows. There are several privately held caves with similar environments. Your budget and space requirements would define the choice that best meets your needs.

> How cold or hot can it get inside Mammoth Cave?
>
> Temperatures inside the cave vary somewhat, but usually hover around 54° Fahrenheit, year-round. In the "variable temperature zones" close to the entrances, wind chills in winter can dip below freezing, or temperatures can rise to around 60°.
> [Source](https://www.nps.gov/maca/faqs.htm)

If you insist on Forest, then the answer by [Olin, is the most correct](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5184/what-is-a-place-in-the-u-s-a-that-is-between-40-60-degrees-year-round-and-doesn/5543#5543) the answer by [StrongBad](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5184/what-is-a-place-in-the-u-s-a-that-is-between-40-60-degrees-year-round-and-doesn/15524#15524) looks promising but it does not clarify if there are privately held lands available.

Comment: A couple of people have mentioned living, but I did not see that as a requirement anywhere. The OP definitely does not mention the need for private land ownership.

Comment: @StrongBad on re-reading I find you are correct. I may have been incorrectly assuming. Without private land ownership, you are severally limited in length of stay options. Maybe the OP is looking for a get away location, that provides a consistent environment regardless of arrival date/time. In which case your answer has trees, and rare snow.  The OP also does not insist on a limited location, so moving up down and around in your area, potentially provides the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty late, but the southern part of the california northern coast and the california central coast will work.

San Francisco is your best bet as a big city since temperatures barely exceed 75°F in summer and go below 40°F in winter.

Another city is Monterey, CA which might be better because it rains a little bit less there, but still has those similar temperatures. Also, housing is half the price (still expensive) and houses are much bigger.